# EF Code First - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." during database creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Today i was making changes to my database model. I was modifying it for like 2 hours, without compiling it.

So, i have this in my application:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDb>());
```

And usually when i was making changes to my model, it was enough to do this:

```
var tmp = new MyDb();
tmp.Categories.Any();
```

And model was recreating itself. But now, after i changed my model, i am getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have totally no idea what does that mean, since i am invoking MyDb(), so this instance is set. What is going on here? How can i check what is wrong?

**Edit:** The thing i discovered just now, is that it's not even trying to recreate database. I have set this:

```
 public class MyDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ScykDb>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ScykDb context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
            (code...)
         }
     }
```

Into my application_start:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyDatabaseInitializer());
```

And i put a breakpoint in this method, and it's not even hitting it!

Comment: Can you share your EF models? What is MyDb? Is that your DataContext class? Do you mean that you changed your EF models and now you're getting that error without updating the database?

Comment: My EF models are 600 lines long, so it's no use, noone will read through that. And i mean, that i have this model for some time now, and whenever i was doing changes to it, it was recreating database without errors. Now i have error and i don't know what to do.

Comment: And yes, MyDb() is my DbContext class.

Comment: It might be that some change in your models is not getting initialized properly and is generating the error. I.E. if you need to new-up a related object in your Categories model or something like that.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? Also, is the exception being thrown at `tmp.Categories.Any()`?

Comment: @IronMan84: Call stack? You mean this? Scyk.DLL!Scyk.Controllers.HomeController.Index() Line 38 + 0x20 bytes C# 

And yes, it's being thrown at `tmp.Categories.Any()`

Comment: @IronMan84: I think that this is full callstack: http://wklej.org/hash/56f058e247b/

Comment: Ok, and what models did you change?

Comment: @IronMan84: Well that's the problem, if i knew i would reverse it step by step. I changed a whole lot, and the main change is changing primary key in my table, which included almost all tables. One thing i can see now, is that when i turn off my `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`, im getting an error. But as for me that means only, that this thing tries to create model, nothing else. :s

Comment: Are you using any form of source control for this?

Comment: Yes, but reversing it is the last thing i wanna do. I have whole application connected to this which would crash if i changed it. I am thinking about making this model stand-alone and reversing the changes, but as i said it's the last thing i wanna do. Aren't there any other options? :/

Comment: Hmmm...Are you using Migrations at all?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this and I had not before. It drove me nuts till I figured out what I was doing.  If you have a  model that has a List to another model, make sure to have a constructor on your model initialize the list.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. For anyone who enters here, here's the solution:

I have no idea how that works, but i commented out ALL my [ForeignKey] attributes and ALL my fluent api configuration. I then started the project, and fixed errors that it was throwing by using ONLY fluent api. This helped. All works just fine now.